# How to log to a new file in every route handler function?

Tags: python, flask, logging

In my flask api, I have a function like this:

```
@app.route('/sample_route')
def my_func():
   # log something...
   # doing something...
   # log the processing results to a new .log file
```

I want to create a new `.log` file every time a new request comes to `my_func` function. I've tried some ways but none of them works correctly.

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new file in your route function with

```py
current_log_file = open(f"{logfilename}.log", "w")
```

if there is no file with the fitting filename, a new file will be created

This is the implementation i use for my TFTP Server

Comment: Thank you, but I prefer to use python logging module. Its capabilities will be more useful for my code with respect to the necessity of flexibility and scalability.

Comment: okay, it would be best if you specify what module your using if you have another question in the Future :)

Answer (score 0):

I reviewed my code and finally found the solution.

```
@app.route('/sample_route')
def my_func():
   logger = logging.getLogger("my_logger")

   # If you don't set level to INFO or DEBUG, the logs with these levels will no longer be printed to stdout/stderr or file.
   logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG) 

   # log something...

   date_time = jdatetime.datetime.now()
   file_handler = logging.FileHandler(
       filename + date_time.strftime('-%Y-%m-%d:%H-%M-%S') + '.log'
    )

   formatter = logging.Formatter(
        '%(asctime)s,%(levelname)s,%(message)s', datefmt='%Y-%m-%d,%H:%M:%S'
    )

   file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
   logger.addHandler(file_handler)

   # doing something...

   # log the processing results to a new .log file

   logger.removeHandler(file_handler)
   file_handler.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this [python log router](https://github.com/IBM/python-log-router) library. This library lets you route logs based on a discriminator (an extra field in the LogRecord object). If you use the default configuration calling `setup_logging(use_default_config=True)`, you can then log to a different file for each request as follows:

```py
logging.info("doing something", {extra: jdatetime.datetime.now()})
```